# curl call to get rest assured request

Tags: rest-assured

I am not able to get the path params from below curl call to get data:

```
curl -X GET "http://url.co/base_path?sort_by=question_title&order=ASC&start_index=0&limit=20" -H "accept: application/json" -H "session-token: sessionToken"
```

My Rest Assured call looks like below:

```
Response response = given().header("accept", "application/json").header("session-token", accessToken)
            .pathParam("sort_by", "question_title")
            .pathParam("order", "ASC").pathParam("start_index", 0)
            .pathParam("limit", 20)
            .when().get("?{sort_by}/{order}/{start_index}/{limit}");
```

This is giving me Response as below:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Please enter correct sorting key.","message_code":184,"data":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you are confusing query param with path param. Any URL which has `?` and is followed by some params is query param while pathe params don't have `?` It is an extension of URL with values directly.

So your code will change as,

```
Response response = given()
  .baseURI ("http://url.co")
  .basePath ("/base_path")
  .header("accept", "application/json")
  .header("session-token", accessToken)
  .queryParam("sort_by", "question_title")
  .queryParam("order", "ASC")
  .queryParam("start_index", 0)
  .queryParam("limit", 20)
  .when()
  .get();
```

Now all the query params will be automatically be added to the URL by prefixing it with `?`.

This should work for your case.